# How do you select the indexes of a pandas dataframe as a series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have tried resetting the index and then selecting that column then setting the index again like so:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=False)
country_names = df['Country'] #the Series I want to select
df.set_index('Country',drop=True,inplace=True)
```

But it seems like there should be a better way to do this.

Comment: What is the intended purpose of `df['Country']` line?

Comment: just to show that I am trying to select one of the columns of the dataframe

Comment: It's the "select" word in struggling to understand. To get index values you can do `df.index.values` for example, but the rest of the question is about setting the index to the values of another column. So `df['Country']` isn't actually intended to do something in the code, it's just for illustration?

Comment: `df.index.to_series()` ?

Comment: So I edited it show that i want to be able to obtain a series called country_names.  df.index.to_series() works, thank you!

Comment: You weren't clear with what you wanted. Next time, instead of posting a couple of lines of defunct code with a "is there a better way..." you should properly describe your problem, so you don't force people to _guess_ what you want in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and I apologize this is my first question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the index of a dataframe as a `pd.series` object you can use the `to_series` method, for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 3], index=['a', 'b'])
df.index.to_series()

a    a
b    b
dtype: object
```